# Get the hostname in the url using PHP on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Inside a PHP application hosted on Elastic Benstalk I'd like to get and use the host, or domain, part of the url the client used to load the page.

In the past, but on non AWS servers, I have used:

```
$hostname = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
```

which would return `example.com` from a url like `http://example.com/index.html`. What I'm getting from my code deployed on elastic beanstalk appears to be the ip address of the running instance; it's something like `53.123.123.123`.

Is there a way to get the host name - or domain name - of the url that the client web browser requested from my Elastic Beanstalk PHP Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look in

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

Instead